# Xcode 8 simulator slow & laggy while building app

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode8

Xcode iOS simulator running incredibly slow while app is building. UI and response is very laggy.

I am using Xcode 8.0 release on OSX 10.11.6

Has anyone else experienced this? If so anyone have any solutions?

Comment: I am also having this issue! 
It's very annoying,can't even develop on simulator.

Using Xcode8.1beta, latest macOS sierra downloaded from AppStore
MBPR late 2013 with 8G Ram

Comment: same here with MacBook 12inch early 2015, iOS10 and XCode 8.0 (8A218a).

Comment: I've been getting this for the past week or two now. Getting the same behaviour on three different computers, a 2013 MacBook Pro with 8GB of RAM and two different 2015 MacBook Pros with 16GB of RAM each, so it is definitely not a hardware problem. Using Xcode 8.1 (8B62). One of the 2015 Macs is running Sierra and the other two are running El Capitan.

Answer (score 1):

The iOS Simulator does not have access to the GPU.  It makes use of the CPU for all rendering.

Compilation takes up a ton of your CPU and disk I/O bandwidth.

Given that, you should expect the simulator to run slower than normal than when you're not compiling because it is getting resource starved by the compilation.

Comment: I don't believe that is the case. It lags where it is unusable, this does not occur all the time which leads me to think this is Xcode 8 issue.

Comment: Not sure why you think that, but you're free to your opinion.  Without any evidence to suggest otherwise, there's not much chance you're going to convince me of that.  I know where the performance problems are in the sim, and taking CPU away from it with background tasks (like compilation) are going to kill its already poor graphics performance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was solved after upgrading to macOS Sierra 10.12.5 Beta